# How to update a specific version in Jackrabbit using OCM Version Management

Tags: jackrabbit

I curious about it is possible to update a specific version of @Node model using JackRabbit OCM? For example I have a DTO like this:

```
@Node(jcrMixinTypes = "mix:versionable")
public class Something implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6651266612240053364L;

    @Field(path = true)
    private String path;

    @Field
    private String xml;

    @Field
    private Long version;

    public String getPath() {
        return this.path;
    }

    public void setPath(final String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public String getXml() {
        return this.xml;
    }

    public void setXml(final String xml) {
        this.xml = xml;
    }    

    public Long getVersion() {
        return this.version;
    }

    public void setVersion(final Long version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

}
```

And created multiple versions e.q. on path name: /abc
Named: 'jcr:rootVersion', '1.0', '1.1'.
How can I update all of these specific versions DTO content e.g. the xml property and save in the JackRabbit repository without creating new versions?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can't update previous versions. Why would you want to? They are there to preserve the changes.

Or if you don't want to create a new version every time you save then don't! Are you calling check[in/out/point]? Remove them so you only save changes to the current version.